# A level expression was used. MDX issue while getting multiple columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, mdx

I am trying to get the complete details about the shop in ResultSet by Using MDX.

I've tried the following query:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Shop Code]
  AS '[Shop Hierarchy].[Shop Code].[Shop Code]'
  MEMBER [Measures].[Shop Name]
  AS '[Shop Hierarchy].[Shop Name].[Shop Name]'
  MEMBER [Measures].[Area]
  AS '[Shop Hierarchy].[Area].[Area]' 

SELECT  {
   [Measures].[Shop Code],
   [Measures].[Shop Name],
   [Measures].[Area]

   } ON COLUMNS , 
   NON EMPTY [Shop Hierarchy].[Shop Code].[Shop Code] ON ROWS 

FROM [Consolidated Sales]
```

but the output I'm getting is:

[image]

I don't know why there are repeating #Error is present.

on mouser hover it is showing the following Error Message:

**the function expects a string or numeric expression for the argument a level expression was used**

I wrote this query by studying the following:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/bcf8fe75-136a-4d70-a77d-d1bf5d88d365/mdx-to-read-multiple-attributes-from-a-dimension?forum=sqlanalysisservices

I am new to MDX. please help me resolve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes a measure needs to return a number or string.

Maybe try amending like follows:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Shop Code]
  AS [Shop Hierarchy].[Shop Code].[Shop Code].CURRENT MEMBER.MEMBER_CAPTION
  MEMBER [Measures].[Shop Name]
  AS [Shop Hierarchy].[Shop Name].[Shop Name] .CURRENT MEMBER.MEMBER_CAPTION
  MEMBER [Measures].[Area]
  AS [Shop Hierarchy].[Area].[Area] .CURRENT MEMBER.MEMBER_CAPTION
```